# How to debug when OS kills postgres for high memory usage

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, performance, postgresql-performance

I am running Postgres 9.4 server in a VPS running Ubuntu. It gets killed often (multiple times in a day).

This is the message from `dmesg`

> Out of memory: Kill process 1020 (postgres) score 64 or sacrifice child
>
> Killed process 1020 (postgres) total-vm:445764kB, anon-rss:140640kB, file-rss:136092kB

How to debug what is causing this crash? Is it long running queries or some misconfiguration of the server or lots of idle connections open?

Answer (score 5):

It's the OOM killer in the Linux kernel. [Disable VM overcommit, per the advice in the PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/kernel-resources.html#LINUX-MEMORY-OVERCOMMIT).